# Comparing between Calendar's DAY_OF_WEEK constants and Enum of days of weeks

Tags: java, enums, calendar

I have an `EnumSet<Days>`, where `Days` is an `Enum` of all the days of the week, starting with Sunday at ordinal 0. I am receiving an integer from `someCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)`, which is a constant representing a day of the week starting with Sunday at 1, up through Saturday at 7. I need to know if the day of the week represented by that integer is in my `EnumSet`. Would it be reasonable to say:

```
private EnumSet<Days> selectedDays;
private final Days[] allDays = Days.values();

private boolean checkDayOfWeek(int day){
    return (selectedDays.contains(allDays[day - 1]));
}
```

The constants in `Calendar` are published in the API, so is it reasonable to assume they will not change? Is there a more elegant solution that I'm not seeing? Do they remain the same regardless of locality? The only other idea I've had is a series of ugly if-statements.

Comment: The constants in `Calendar` will definitely not change.

Comment: And if they ever do your unit test will break . You have unit tests right :)

Comment: I do :). But I don't really want to be working on this app forever. Some day I will stop running the unit tests regularly.